# Dictionary error in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file in the format:

```
0000 | a1_1,a3_2 | b2_1, b3_2
0001 | a1_3 | b4_1
```

and I'm trying to create a dictionary which has

```
{ 'a1' : set(['b2', 'b3', 'b4']), 'a3': set(['b2', 'b3']) }
```

and this is how my code looks like:

```
def get_ids(row, col):
    ids = set()
    x = row.strip().split('|')
    for a in x[col].split(','):
        ids.add(a.split('_')[0])
    return ids

def add_to_dictionary(funky_dictionary,key, values):
    if key in funky_dictionary:
        funky_dictionary[key].update(values)
    else:
        funky_dictionary[key] = values


def get_dict(input_file):
    funky_dictionary = {}
    with open(input_file,'r') as ip:
        for row in ip:
            a_ids = get_ids(row,1)
            b_ids = get_ids(row,2)
            for key in a_ids:
                add_to_dictionary(funky_dictionary,key,b_ids)
    return funky_dictionary
```

So my problem is this when I lookup values for certain key in the dictionary, it returns me with way more values than expected. E.g.

For the above example the expected value of `a3` would be `set(['b2', ' b3'])`
However with the code, I'm getting `set(['b2', ' b3', 'b4'])`

I cant figure out whats wrong with the code. Any help?

Comment: You're not going to get memory leaks in normal Python code. Can you format your dictionary in the second code block to be a Python dictionary? It's not clear what that format represents.

Comment: There you go. Why down vote? Btw. I'm doing this for a ~400 Mb file. Shouldn't have had any issues with filesize. I got enough resources.

Comment: There have been more views than just myself. Consider the possibility that I was not the one to downvote. Another thing that might help improve the question would be example output versus what was expected.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to connect very closely to your code. You're not creating `set`s, nor are you preserving the `_2` suffixes on the values in the last column. Cound the "way more values than expected" just be duplicates that you're not cleaning up with a `set`? Can you give an example of input data that produces unexpected output?

Comment: My bad, was testing different versions of the code. Working on the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that many of your dictionary's values are in fact references to the same `set` instances. In your example data, when the first line is processed, `'a1'` and `'a3'` both get mapped to the same `set` object (containing `'b2'` and `'b3'`). When you process the second line and call `update` on that set via the key `'a1'`, you'll see the added value through `'a3'` too, since both values are references to the same `set`.

You need to change the code so that each value is a separate `set` object. I'd suggest getting rid of `add_to_dictionary` and just using the dictionary's own [`setdefault` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), like this:

```
for key in a_ids:
    funky_dictionary.setdefault(key, set()).update(b_ids)
```

This code always starts with a new empty set for a new key, and always updates it with new values (rather than adding a reference to the `b_ids` set to the dictionary directly).

Comment: Yes, that indeed was the error. Seems so trivial when you finally catch it. Thanks a lot!